# idempotents in $C(\mathbb{N})$, $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, idempotents

Let $ X$ be a topological space. The set $C(X)$ is all continuous, real valued functions on $X$, so that $C(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{X}$.

Define:

$C^* (X) = \{ f \in C(X) \vert \quad  f\quad  is \quad bounded \}$.

consider the subspace $\mathbb{R}$ , $ \mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{N}$  and $ \mathbb{N}^{*} = \{ 1, 1/2, .........., 1/n ,...... 0 \} $ of $ \mathbb{R}$ , and the ring $ C $ and  $ C ^{*}$ for each  of these spaces. each of these rings is of cardinal $ c$.

> Will you help me solve these problems?

a:$ C ( \mathbb{R} )$ has just two idempotents, $ \mathbb{N}^{*}$ has exactly $\aleph_{0}$, and $ C ( \mathbb{Q} )$ and $ C ( \mathbb{N} )$ have cardinal $ c$.

b: every nonzero idempotent in   $ C ( \mathbb{Q} )$     is a sum  of two nonzero idempotents.  in    $ C ( \mathbb{N} )$, and in  $ C ( \mathbb{N^{*}} )$,some, but not all idempotents have this property.

c: Except for the obvious identity   $C ( \mathbb{N}^{*} ) = C^{*} ( \mathbb{N}^{*} )$ , no two of the rings in question are isomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...the ring $C$ and $C^*$ for each of these spaces."*? Also, please share your efforts.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^*$ is a not a ring. When you say it has infinitely many idempotents what do you mean?